# Dynamically add a child to a styled-component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, styled-components

Given:

```
const Item = styled.div`
    color: ${p => p.blue ? 'blue' : 'black'};
`;
```

I need to add a dom element dynamically under a div tag(Item) with a styled component.
If this were JQuery or JavaScript, you need to get the class or id of the div,

How do you do it in react?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Text style={[styles.existingStyle, { color: this.state.blue ? 'blue' : 'red' } ]}>
```

First you dump the style into an array, and you define the second style.
In your second style, define the key first, then using ternary operator to decide the value of it

Comment: Hmm. If you want to use like appendChild, innerHtml (), you need to get the ID or class name of the tag. Can you give ID or tag if you make it with styled-components?